# Trying to convert mysql timestamp to time using strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, session, time

`strtotime($_SESSION['starttime'])`
I tried to convert the mysql time stored as $_SESSION['starttime'] of value 1422094831 but I want to convert the resulting to time using strtotime but returns no value. What could be wrong?

Comment: In what format you want it to convert ?

Comment: post your session time.

Comment: If it's already a timestamp, `strtotime` is probably not what you want. That converts a string value into a timestamp. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @Jeremiah please does the time() outputs a time stamp???

Comment: @FALETINO http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime()` is used to create a timestamp, not convert it to a date. If your session variable stores a timestamp, try using the `date()` function to convert it to a more readable format.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", $yourTimestamp); //Will print YYYY-MM-DD format date
```

The [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) will help you using the `date()` function correctly.

If that's not what you want to do then please provide more information in your question, from what I understand you already have a timestamp.

Comment: This is what i wanted to do ` time()-strtotime($_SESSION['starttime']); `